# I am using Asp.net client side validators but they don't work when I run through IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtContact" ErrorMessage="Enter Max 10 digit number"
    ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="10"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: I think you are using RangeValidator where we have to set the "Type" property to appropriate type like Integer, string etc.......Secondly your error message shows "Enter Max 10 DIGIT number" and MaximumValue is 10...these two are not same MaximumValue=10 means you can enter a value which is less than or equal to 10

Answer (score 0):

When you have javascript errors, then the validators can stop working.

Now, when you move from local to iis, some scripts may not load correctly any more if you do not check if the path works the same as local. And if some scripts not load, then this may affect the script that calidators creates.

so open your browser tools and look what script is not loaded, what javascript throw error, and correct that error, that is probably the non right script path.